# CSS Wrapper div isn't working

Tags: html, css, wrapper

http://jsfiddle.net/xVNN9/1/

In this fiddle i tired to wrap a div around all other divs and give it a background color. Sadly this doesn't work as intended, its like the wrap div doesn't exist. Whats wrong with this fiddle? All divs should be placed in a grey box, the background color of wrap div.

```
<div class="wrap">

<div class="line">a</div>
<div class="line">b</div>
<div class="line">c</div>
<div class="line">d</div>

<div class="first">e</div>
<div class="line">f</div>
<div class="line">g</div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
div.wrap {background-color:#CFCFCF;}

div.line {float:left;background-color:#00FF00; margin:5px; }
div.first {clear:both; float:left; margin:5px;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add `display: inline-block` to the .wrap

Comment: This works even better. I like it better than overflow:hidden.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to clear your floated elements. To do this just add `overflow: hidden` to your `.wrap`

Comment: Chris Coyier explains it here far better than I could here http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way to clear your elements and thus say that the parent div should wrap **everything** inside it is to add a clearing div at the end.

By default the wrapper dimensions are not updated when you add floating elements inside it. But when you clear them the dimensions update to reach the end of the last cleared/floating element.

`<div style="clear: both"></div>`

See the DEMO here: http://jsfiddle.net/xVNN9/5/

Comment: This is also a great way to do it. I like    display:inline-block most, but this is also very nice. But again, i don't really understand how this works.